# É possivel criar jogos mobile apenas com c#?

Tags: c#, android, ios, mobile, jogos

É possivel criar apps mobile tanto quanto Android quanto IOS usando apenas C# no visual studio? o app em questão é um jogo

Comment: Sim, é possível. Só isso que quer saber?

Answer (score 2):

A melhor forma para se fazer isso com C# seria com o [Unity](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/mobile-development), que é feito especialmente para jogos e possui suporte mobile.

Outra maneira seria com o [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/customers/gaming), mas eu diria que não é a melhor opção.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que umas das melhores formas de criar Apps em C# seria com Xamarin.

Da uma olhada nesse link abaixo, acho que é exatamente o que você procura.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/Dn879698.aspx